# How to change the Agent label in Jenkins depending on Branch Name

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a Jenkin Pipeline for below task.

- Pull the latest code from **vsts**
- Build the code and create .jar file out of it
- creating a Docker image on the basis of the jar
- tag the image
- push the image into Docker registry

for this, I have written below Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent {
       label "master"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo '..........................Building Jar..........................'
                sh 'npm install'

            }
        }
        stage('Build-Image') {
            steps {
                echo '..........................Building Image..........................'
                sh 'sudo docker build -t some-org/admin-portal:v0.1 --build-arg PORT=9007 --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=develop .'
            }
        }
        stage('Tag-Image') {
            steps {
                echo '..........................Taging Image..........................'
                sh 'sudo docker login some-repo -u username001 -p password'
                sh 'sudo docker tag some-org/admin-portal:v0.1 some.dtr.io/some-org/admin-portal:v0.1'
            }
        }
        stage('Push-Image') {
            steps {
                echo '..........................Pushing Image..........................'
                sh 'sudo docker push some.dtr.io/some-org/admin-portal:v0.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is Jenkins job configuration snapshot for Pipeline

[image]

My Question is how can I change the agent label depending upon branch name or some conditions.

e.g if the branch is **develop** I want to use **slave1** node and if the branch is **production** I want to use **master**

Any Help will be appreciable.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the agent labels inside the stage, so that you can execute the stages with required agents.

eg:

```
pipeline {
agent none

stages {
    stage('Build') {
      agent {
        label "master"
       }
        steps {
            echo '..........................Building Jar..........................'
            sh 'npm install'

        }
    }
    stage('Build-Image') {

      agent {
        label "master"
       }
        steps {
            echo '..........................Building Image..........................'
            sh 'sudo docker build -t some-org/admin-portal:v0.1 --build-arg PORT=9007 --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=develop .'
        }
    }
    stage('Tag-Image') {

      agent {
        label "slave1"
       }
        steps {
            echo '..........................Taging Image..........................'
            sh 'sudo docker login some-repo -u username001 -p password'
            sh 'sudo docker tag some-org/admin-portal:v0.1 some.dtr.io/some-org/admin-portal:v0.1'
        }
    }
    stage('Push-Image') {

      agent {
        label "slave1"
       }
        steps {
            echo '..........................Pushing Image..........................'
            sh 'sudo docker push some.dtr.io/some-org/admin-portal:v0.1'
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already implemented the `agnet` inside stage. I am looking for assigning  the `agent` on the basis of branch name from where I am pulling the code

Comment: declare a variable and append the value (label name) based on branch name. then use that variable for agents. eg: agent { label <variable>}.

Comment: How can I check the branch name ??

Comment: How/Where did you define 'master' and 'slave1'?